# Is the 'copy' argument in pandas working as intended?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm on a quest to ensure that I never see another `SettingWithCopyWarning` when running my code. After figuratively hours of reading SO threads on this topic, I have more questions, and few answers. Adding to my frustration is that the `copy` argument in various situations seems to be completely ignored.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> pd.__version__
    '0.24.2'

>>> arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 5))  
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr)  # default value for 'copy' argument is False
>>> df._is_view
    True

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, copy=True)  # this should create a copy, but doesn't
>>> df._is_view
    True

>>> df = df.copy()  # this should create a copy, and does
>>> df._is_view
    False

>>> df.astype(dtype='float')  # default value for 'copy' argument is True
>>> df._is_view
    True
```

1. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `copy` argument in these examples?
2. Is the `_is_view` attribute (un)reliable?
3. In the cases of the `DataFrame` constructor and the `astype` method, what are the recommended approaches for creating/preserving copy status?

Comment: As for your question, I would not bank on `_is_view` returning very helpful results, nor assuming its behaviour will not change. it is an internal variable, and can be changed or removed at any time.

Comment: `copy=True` or `copy=False` work as expected, I see the expected behaviour when I modify the dataframe. As long as you don't use chained indexing, you should not have to worry about the warning.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

> copy : boolean, default False Copy data from inputs. Only affects
>   DataFrame / 2d ndarray input

So copy here is related to the input that you pass to the DataFrame constructor.
Continuing from your example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3))
print(arr)
[[5 0 3]
 [3 7 9]
 [3 5 2]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, copy=False)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr, copy=True)
```

---

```
# Change the first cell of the numpy array to -999
arr[0, 0] = 999

print(df1)
     0  1  2
0  999  0  3
1    3  7  9
2    3  5  2

print(df2)
   0  1  2
0  5  0  3
1  3  7  9
2  3  5  2
```

So when you pass `copy=True`, it does create a copy of the input array and uses that as the underlying numpy array representation.

`_is_view`, on the other hand, is related to whether or not that DataFrame is copied from another DataFrame. Take a look at these selections:

```
# Start with a DataFrame which has mixed types
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': list('abc'), 'C': [1., 2., 3,]})

df['A']._is_view  # single column selection returns a view
Out: True

df[['A', 'B']]._is_view  # if you select multiple columns it becomes a copy
Out: False

df.loc[[0, 1], 'A']._is_view  # if you select some rows it is a copy again
Out: False

df.loc[:, 'A']._is_view  # same as selecting a single column
Out: True
```

Now if you assign these to variables and change them they will all raise a warning but in the simplest cases the changes you make to the views will work but the changes to the copies will stay in the copies. Similarly,

```
df['A'].replace(1, 2, inplace=True)
```

will work. But

```
df[['A', 'B']].replace('a', 'b', inplace=True)
```

won't change 'a' to 'b'. Because the replace method is called on a copy of the sliced DataFrame -- it is actually changing the copy and leaving the original `df` unchanged. But as cs95 commented, `_is_view` is a private attribute. These may change in the future and a user shouldn't rely on these implementation details in general.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand that `_is_view` isn't something I should use in perpetuity; it just seemed like a useful shortcut to help me wrap my head around all this copy/view business. Even after your explanation, I'm still not clear whey `pd.Dataframe(data=arr, copy=True)._is_view` would be `True`. Isn't the `copy` kwarg there specifically to ensure that the result is not a view?